# Between the 2nd and 3th scrollable tabs border appeared which must not be there

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, native-base

I am using react-native scrollable tabs and native-base. Between the 2nd and 3th scrollable tabs border appeared which must not be there. I tried to add borderLeftWidth:0, marginLeft:0 in the style object but it haven't solved the trouble.[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNXyH.png)

Here is the code.

```
return (
      <Container style={{backgroundColor: '#494949'}}>
        <CommonHeader {...this.props} />
          <Tabs tabBarUnderlineStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#42d4f4' }}>
            <Tab tabStyle={{backgroundColor: '#EEE'}}
                 heading="Popular"
                 activeTextStyle={{ color: '#42d4f4' }}
                 activeTabStyle={{backgroundColor: '#EEE'}}
                 textStyle={{ color: 'grey' }}>
              <Articles {...this.props} />
            </Tab>
            <Tab tabStyle={{backgroundColor: '#EEE'}}
                 heading="New"
                 activeTextStyle={{ color: '#42d4f4' }}
                 activeTabStyle={{backgroundColor: '#EEE'}}
                 textStyle={{ color: 'grey' }} >
              <ArticlesNew {...this.props} />
            </Tab>
            <Tab tabStyle={{backgroundColor: '#EEE', borderLeftWidth:0,marginLeft:0}}
                 heading="Pro"
                 activeTextStyle={{ color: '#42d4f4' }}
                 activeTabStyle={{backgroundColor: '#EEE'}}
                 textStyle={{ color: 'grey' }} >
              <ProContent {...this.props} />
            </Tab>

          </Tabs>
      </Container>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently found the same problem with the NativeBase `ScrollableTab` component. The problem here is that the TabBar does always have it's own background color which can not be set via the NativeBase [theme colors](https://docs.nativebase.io/Customize.html#Customize). To solve my problem i just simply hardcoded the background color as style property of the `ScrollableTab` component.

```
        <Tabs
          renderTabBar={()=> <ScrollableTab style={{backgroundColor: "#ff000" />}>
          ....
        </Tabs>
```

(Hope this helps you, since it is my very first post to StackOverflow :-))

Comment: Thank you sooooo much, you save my life